# Postgres sequence function error: relation does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a new sequence if one does not exist based on year and text. I found an example, but I get error > SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation "2023_aa" does not exist
Where: PL/pgSQL function teenusjuhtum_generator(integer,text) line 17 at RETURN

function is following:

```
create or replace function teenusjuhtum_generator(year integer, liik text) returns bigint as $$
declare
    _seq_name text := year || '_' || liik;
begin
   case (select c.relkind = 'S':: "char"
         from pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
         join pg_catalog.pg_class c on c.relnamespace = n."oid"
         where n.nspname = current_schema() --or provide your schema
         and c.relname = _seq_name)
   when true then
        raise notice 'true';
   when false then
         RAISE EXCEPTION '% is not a sequence!', _seq_name;
   else
        EXECUTE format('CREATE SEQUENCE %I MINVALUE 1 INCREMENT BY 1', _seq_name);
   end case;
return nextval(_seq_name);
end
$$ language plpgsql
```

I run it like this: `select teenusjuhtum_generator(2023, 'AA');`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the parameter `AA`, in capital letters, and the error complains about `2023_aa` not being found. Note the `aa` is now in lower case.

When you build the sequence creation statement, using `%I`, it puts double quotes around capitalized text, so the sequence name will be `"2023_AA"`. When you query `nextval`, you are not adding double quotes anymore, so it falls back on the default lowercase name, and it is not found.

You can either use (force) lowercase parameters, or use `%s%` instead to build the lowercase name, or you could also doublequote the sequence name when using it.